# How to plot time-dependent vector field?

Tags: plotting

My problem is:
plot the motion of the top of the vector $E$ (electric field) on the plane 
$$(k_1 - k_2)z = 0.25 \pi$$.
Vector components are
$$E_x = \cos(\omega t - 0.5(k_1 + k_2)z - 0.5(k_1-k_2)z)$$
$$E_y = \cos(\omega t - 0.5(k_1 + k_2)z + 0.5(k_1-k_2)z)$$
where $0\le t \le \dfrac{2 \pi}{\omega}$.
It should looks like the light is elliptically polarized.
Which function should I use for this? You can just say me suitable function. Thank you)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you at least present your equations in Mathematica syntax as well, so anybody interested in helping you can copy / paste them, rather than having to retype them?

Comment: `ParametricPlot3D` may be useful.

Comment: @xslittlegrass ParametricPlot is perfect. Thank you very much. I used 2D version because I have only 2 space coordinates. But anyway your advice is a super helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @xslittlegrass for the hint.
So, the solution

```
omega = 2 Pi;
a = 0.1; 
b = 0.2; 
c = 300; 
n1 = 10^(-4); n2 = 10^(-7);
k1 = n1 omega/c; k2 = n2 omega/c;
r = 0.25; z = r Pi/ (k1 - k2);
s = 10;
ParametricPlot[{2 a Cos[omega t - 0.5 (k1 + k2) z - 0.5 (k1 - k2) z] ,
   2 b Cos[omega t - 0.5 (k1 + k2) z + 0.5 (k1 - k2) z] }, {t, 0, 
  2 Pi/omega}]
```

I just added some additional parameters. Eventually I got
[image]